# How to arrange numbers on grid to satisfy a minimum condition?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-optimization, combinatorial-designs

Take an $N \times M$ rectangular grid and arrange the integers from $1$ to $ N M$ so that all grid point gets an assignment without repetition, and let the integer number on location (grid point) $n,m$ be denoted by $k_{nm}$ with $1\le k_{nm}\le NM$. Calculate the differences between the neighbors: $|k_{n,m}-k_{n,m+1}|$, $|k_{n,m-1}-k_{n,m}|$, $|k_{n,m}-k_{n+1,m+1}|$, etc., and let the *smallest* difference among all the neighboring locations be $d^*$; obviously $d^*\ge 1$.

Which arrangement will *maximize* $d^*$?

---

Following the suggestion of @Steven here is his solution for the case $N=1$ that is a grid $1\times M$:

$$M=2K \qquad \text {and} \quad d^*=K-1\\
\mathbf b_1 = [1, K+1, 2, K+2, 3, K+3,4,...,2K-2, K-2, 2K-1, K-1, 2K]\\
k=1,2,..,K\\
a_{2k-1} = k; \\
a_{2k}= K+k$$
or
$$M=2K-1 \qquad \text {and} \quad d^*=K-1\\
\mathbf b_1 = [1, K+1, 2, K+2, 3, K+3,4,...,2K-2, K-1, 2K-1, K]\\
k=1,2,..,K\\
a_{2k-1} = k; \\
a_{2k}= K+k$$

This can be easily extended for arbitrary $N\times M$ without changing $d^*$ by adding $M$ to each element in the row $\mathbf b_1 $ to get $\mathbf b_2$, do this for $i=1,2,..N-1;j=1,2,..M:$ $\mathbf b_{i+1}(j)=\mathbf b_i(j)+M$. Repeating this $N$ times will produce an $N\times M$ grid with $d^*=K-1.$

Here it is an $8\times 8$ grid:

$$\begin{matrix}
 1 &  5 &  2 &  6 &  3 &  7 &  4 &  8\\
 9 & 13 & 10 & 14 & 11 & 15 & 12 & 16\\
17 & 21 & 18 & 22 & 19 & 23 & 20 & 24\\
25 & 29 & 26 & 30 & 27 & 31 & 28 & 32\\
33 & 37 & 34 & 38 & 35 & 39 & 36 & 40\\
41 & 45 & 42 & 46 & 43 & 47 & 44 & 48\\
49 & 53 & 50 & 54 & 51 & 55 & 52 & 56\\
57 & 61 & 58 & 62 & 59 & 63 & 60 & 64
\end{matrix}$$

Then my question is if this construction can be improved on?

Comment: I mean, isn't it always possible to get $1?$ Maybe I'm misunderstanding what $d^*$ is.

Comment: Of course the answer is not always 1. For example in the 1D case, i believe you can always get $d^* = \lfloor{(N-1)/2}\rfloor$.  Like [1,5,2,6,3,7,2,8].

Comment: @Steven I think there is two $2$s and no $4$ in your pattern. However something like that may be optimal.

Comment: @P.Quinton: That's probably just a typo. if you replace the second "2", with "4", you still get differences that are all $\geq \lfloor(N-1)/2\rfloor$.

Comment: Do you only consider "real neighbor" differences or "wrapped around" differences as well? I.e. is e.g. $(1,1)$ considered a neighbor of $(1,M)$ or not?

Comment: @jpvee I am only interested in "real neighbor" differences (diagonal included), plane topology, but the question on a sphere or torus or whatever could tickle mathematicians here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation of my previous, erroneous answer (thanks to @nickgard and @hyportnex for pointing out that I missed the fact that neighbors include diagonals):

If I'm not mistaken, the value of $d^\ast$ in your $8\times8$ example is $3$.

This can improved, e.g. by starting with a pattern of non-neighboring fields moving their way up:

\begin{matrix}
. & . & 15 & . & . & . & 16 & .\\
12 & . & . & . & 14 & . & . & .\\
. & . & 11 & . & . & . & 13 & .\\
8 & . & . & . & 10 & . & . & .\\
. & . & 7 & . & . & . & 9 & .\\
4 & . & . & . & 6 & . & . & .\\
. & . & 3 & . & . & . & 5 & .\\
1 & . & . & . & 2 & . & . & .\\
\end{matrix}

Then, continue in a similar manner with the remaining numbers:

\begin{matrix}
46 & 62 & 15 & 31 & 48 & 64 & 16 & 32\\
12 & 28 & 45 & 61 & 14 & 30 & 47 & 63\\
42 & 58 & 11 & 27 & 44 & 60 & 13 & 29\\
 8 & 24 & 41 & 57 & 10 & 26 & 43 & 59\\
38 & 54 &  7 & 23 & 40 & 56 &  9 & 25\\
 4 & 20 & 37 & 53 &  6 & 22 & 39 & 55\\
34 & 50 &  3 & 19 & 36 & 52 &  5 & 21\\
 1 & 17 & 33 & 49 &  2 & 18 & 35 & 51\\
\end{matrix}

Now, the smallest difference between neighbors is $d^\ast=13$.

Comment: very interesting. could you please describe the method/steps by which you created this arrangement?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an $8 \times 8$ arrangement with $d^*=15$, obtained via integer linear programming:

```
37 18 57  7 49 16  1 17 
53  3 38 23 64 31 47 32 
34 19 54  8 46 14 62 15 
50  2 39 24 61 29 45 30 
35 20 55  9 44 12 60 11 
51  5 40 25 59 27 43 28 
36 21 56 10 42  6 63 13 
52  4 41 26 58 22 48 33
```

Comment: could you publish the code and the time it took to run the calculation?